# jsPDF units and HTML units are not aligned in the generated PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0oa3uf9b/
(I don't know if you'll actually be able to download the file due to browser security, etc. but the code would work fine if you put it in a local file.)

I have tried two different methods of generating my PDF from an HTML element. Each method sets the same element as the source; this `div` has `width: 4in` and `height: 2in`.

For method 1, I set the `format` for jsPDF as the `.width()` and `.height()` values of the div from jQuery.

For method 2, I set the `format` to be `unit: "in"` and `format: [4,2]`.

Neither method works entirely.

Method 1 will generate the pdf correctly, but the actual page size of the pdf is not 2x4in.

This is what Adobe Reader DC tells me about the PDF:[image]

Method 2 has a correct page size of 2x4in., but generates just a ton of blank pages for the PDF...

Adobe:[image]

I can't figure out why, when I specify a 2x4in page size for jsPDF, the generated PDF is just full of blank pages, and the only way to generate a correct PDF is by using the width and height properties, which then aren't 2x4in even though the HTML/CSS is set to 2x4in.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @KJ Yeah, it's odd... I actually decided to use `html2canvas` to generate an image, and then use `jsPDF.addImage()`, instead of calling `jsPDF.html()` and letting it do it's own work with `html2canvas` and `dompurify;` and it's working much much better. I will post my solution once I've got it mostly worked out.

Answer (score 0):

**For some reason jsPDF's usage of html2canvas appears to be broken, but if you call html2canvas yourself you can make it work**

Here is a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k47zjb26/ (again, doesn't seem to actually work from within jsFiddle, copy it to local files to test it)

Essentially, replace any of your `jsPDF.html(source)` calls with:

a call to html2canvas, that then calls `jsPDF.addImage()`

```
html2canvas(source, {
    scale: 1
}).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    doc.addImage(canvas, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
    doc.save('MethodCanvas');
});
```